# Short circuit evaluation causing an invalid assignment location error

Tags: julia

The docs for Julia indicate that a valid short-cut to writing out an `if` statement is the syntax

```
<cond> && <statement>
```

I've used this a lot for error messages, e.g. `length(x) < N && error("x is too short")`, and it works as expected. However, the following does not work:

```
x = 3
x < 4 && x = 5
```

I get an error of the form `syntax: invalid assignment location`. What is going on here?

What I'm trying to do is check if `x` is less than `4`, and if it is, then set `x` to `5`. Should I do the following?

```
if x < 4
     x = 5
end
```

Is there a valid short-circuit method for this situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error is caused because the `&&` operator has [higher precedence](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/mathematical-operations/#operator-precedence) than the assignment operator `=` so your line of code is executed as if you would write `(x < 4 && x) = 5`.

For a solution you have to add parantheses.

```
x < 4 && (x = 5)
```

[See my code running in the browser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_julia_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQnROVzJ3N2I1YWM)